# Creating multiple PostgreSQL containers in docker in fedora

Tags: postgresql, docker, fedora

I want to create 2 containers of postgrSQL so that one can be used as DEV and other as DEV_STAGE.

I was able to successfully create one container and it is been assigned to port 5432. But when I'm trying to the second container, it is getting created(sometimes shows the status as EXITED) but not getting started because of the port number issue.

The below are the commands which I ran.
sudo docker run -v "`pwd`/data:/var/lib/pgsql/data:Z" -e POSTGRESQL_USER=user1 -e POSTGRESQL_PASSWORD=password -e POSTGRESQL_DATABASE=test_db -d -p 5432:5432 fedora/postgresql

sudo docker run -v "`pwd`/data_stage:/var/lib/pgsql/data_stage:Z" -e POSTGRESQL_USER=user1 -e POSTGRESQL_PASSWORD=password -e POSTGRESQL_DATABASE=test_db -d -p 5432:5433 fedora/postgresql

I think the port mapping which I'm using is incorrect. But not able to get the correct one.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the answer. I corrected the path. I think flipping the port number will not work too. Because I already have one container which is mapped to 5432. So I can't map the port to 5432 again. The below command with worked for me.  First, I modified Postgres default port to 5433 using export variable PGPORT=5433.

---

```
   sudo docker run -v "`pwd`/data_stg:/var/lib/pgsql/data:Z" -e PGPORT=5433 -e POSTGRESQL_USER=user1 -e POSTGRESQL_PASSWORD=password -e POSTGRESQL_DATABASE=test_db -d -p 5433:5433 fedora/postgresql
```

Answer (score 1):

You have an error in volume definition of the second container. Don't change path after colon, it is mandatory the path is set to `/var/lib/pgsql/data`.

Also you fliped ports mapping. The correct command is like this:

```
sudo docker run -v "`pwd`/data_stage:/var/lib/pgsql/data:Z" -e POSTGRESQL_USER=user1 -e POSTGRESQL_PASSWORD=password -e POSTGRESQL_DATABASE=test_db -d -p 5433:5432 fedora/postgresql
```

If anything goes wrong inspect container logs with `docker logs CONTAINER_ID`